# How do you automatically perform several back-to-back migrations in a set order?

Tags: 7, migrations

I am using the Migrate module to transfer 400,000 items to a new Drupal 7 site.  I had a lot of problems in my first attempt because the database table was too large to import in one go.  To get around this problem, I created several (around 100) smaller migrations which each did a piece of the migration.  This works fine (so far) but the migrations must be done is a specific order.  I would like to set up something that will run each migration, one after the other, in a set order.  The entire process will take several hours, and I would like to set it up and let it run on its own.  How can I do this?

Also, if there is a way create a single migration that can break down one big table query into several smaller queries, I would like to know about it.

Here is a sample of my module activation code (note, the big 400,000 table is not referred to here):

```
function mig_contacts_enable() {

    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $index = substr((1000+$i), 1);
        Migration::registerMigration('ProspectImport', "prospect_import_$index", array('rank' => $i));
    }


    for ($i=0; $i<1; $i++) {
        $index = substr((1000+$i), 1);
        Migration::registerMigration('CustomerImport', "customer_import_$index", array('rank' => $i));
    }  


    for ($i=0; $i<1; $i++) {
        $index = substr((1000+$i), 1);
        Migration::registerMigration('CustomerContactImport', "customer_contact_import_$index", array('rank' => $i));
    } 

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you activate a migration module that contains multiple migrations, they are installed in alphabetical order.  This is the order that they are executed in when you use the UI or:

drush mi --all

I have added a single letter as a prefix to my migration.  This allowed me to arrange my migrations as needed.